# Android run DDMS command from code

Tags: android, ddms

I need to run DDMS commands via java code.
.
So is there any way to run the commands like: geo fix, etc from java code in Android.

Comment: "I need to run DDMS commands via java code." -- why?

Comment: @CommonsWare - I was trying to cancel a system notification, but since it was not possible. So just trying some another ways/tricks/hacks, this was one of them.

Comment: I sincerely hope you fail in your search, because allowing an application to cancel a system notification would be a security hole. However, you can certainly get rid of system notifications or change their behavior via modifications to your own custom firmware.

Answer (score 0):

From [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html)

From the command line: Type ddms (or ./ddms on Mac/Linux) from the tools/ directory.

It refers to the folder called tools inside the sdk you are using.

Comment: Well that's not the question :)